# ath9k module missing after update to kernel 5.8 (Ubuntu 20.04)

Tags: networking, 20.04, kernel, atheros

apt update has upgraded my ubuntu kernel to 5.8 after which my wireless no longer works.

Turns out the ath9k module is missing.

```
sudo modprobe ath9k

modprobe: FATAL: Module ath9k not found in directory /lib/modules/5.8.0-34-generic
```

UPDATE: Output of - dpkg -l | grep linux

```
ii  binutils-x86-64-linux-gnu                  2.34-6ubuntu1                       amd64        GNU binary utilities, for x86-64-linux-gnu target
ii  console-setup-linux                        1.194ubuntu3                        all          Linux specific part of console-setup
ii  libselinux1:amd64                          3.0-1build2                         amd64        SELinux runtime shared libraries
ii  libv4l-0:amd64                             1.18.0-2build1                      amd64        Collection of video4linux support libraries
ii  libv4lconvert0:amd64                       1.18.0-2build1                      amd64        Video4linux frame format conversion library
ii  linux-base                                 4.5ubuntu3.1                        all          Linux image base package
ii  linux-firmware                             1.187.7                             all          Firmware for Linux kernel drivers
ii  linux-headers-5.4.0-58                     5.4.0-58.64                         all          Header files related to Linux kernel version 5.4.0
ii  linux-headers-5.4.0-58-generic             5.4.0-58.64                         amd64        Linux kernel headers for version 5.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-headers-5.4.0-59                     5.4.0-59.65                         all          Header files related to Linux kernel version 5.4.0
ii  linux-headers-5.4.0-59-generic             5.4.0-59.65                         amd64        Linux kernel headers for version 5.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-headers-5.8.0-34-generic             5.8.0-34.37~20.04.2                 amd64        Linux kernel headers for version 5.8.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-hwe-5.8-headers-5.8.0-34             5.8.0-34.37~20.04.2                 all          Header files related to Linux kernel version 5.8.0
rc  linux-image-5.4.0-42-generic               5.4.0-42.46                         amd64        Signed kernel image generic
ii  linux-image-5.4.0-58-generic               5.4.0-58.64                         amd64        Signed kernel image generic
ii  linux-image-5.4.0-59-generic               5.4.0-59.65                         amd64        Signed kernel image generic
ii  linux-image-5.8.0-34-generic               5.8.0-34.37~20.04.2                 amd64        Signed kernel image generic
rc  linux-image-unsigned-5.4.0-59-generic      5.4.0-59.65                         amd64        Linux kernel image for version 5.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-libc-dev:amd64                       5.4.0-59.65                         amd64        Linux Kernel Headers for development
rc  linux-modules-5.4.0-42-generic             5.4.0-42.46                         amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 5.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-modules-5.4.0-58-generic             5.4.0-58.64                         amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 5.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-modules-5.4.0-59-generic             5.4.0-59.65                         amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 5.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-modules-5.8.0-34-generic             5.8.0-34.37~20.04.2                 amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 5.8.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-modules-extra-5.4.0-42-generic       5.4.0-42.46                         amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 5.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-modules-extra-5.4.0-58-generic       5.4.0-58.64                         amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 5.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-modules-extra-5.4.0-59-generic       5.4.0-59.65                         amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 5.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-modules-nvidia-450-5.4.0-58-generic  5.4.0-58.64                         amd64        Linux kernel nvidia modules for version 5.4.0-58
ii  linux-modules-nvidia-450-5.4.0-59-generic  5.4.0-59.65                         amd64        Linux kernel nvidia modules for version 5.4.0-59
ii  linux-modules-nvidia-450-5.8.0-34-generic  5.8.0-34.37~20.04.2                 amd64        Linux kernel nvidia modules for version 5.8.0-34
ii  linux-modules-nvidia-450-generic-hwe-20.04 5.8.0-34.37~20.04.2                 amd64        Extra drivers for nvidia-450 for generic-hwe-20.04
ii  linux-sound-base                           1.0.25+dfsg-0ubuntu5                all          base package for ALSA and OSS sound systems
ii  pptp-linux                                 1.10.0-1build1                      amd64        Point-to-Point Tunneling Protocol (PPTP) Client
ii  syslinux                                   3:6.04~git20190206.bf6db5b4+dfsg1-2 amd64        collection of bootloaders (DOS FAT and NTFS bootloader)
ii  syslinux-common                            3:6.04~git20190206.bf6db5b4+dfsg1-2 all          collection of bootloaders (common)
ii  syslinux-legacy                            2:3.63+dfsg-2ubuntu9                amd64        Bootloader for Linux/i386 using MS-DOS floppies
ii  util-linux                                 2.34-0.1ubuntu9.1                   amd64        miscellaneous system utilities
```

Output of apt show linux-image-generic -a

```
Package: linux-image-generic
Version: 5.4.0.59.62
Priority: optional
Section: kernel
Source: linux-meta
Origin: Ubuntu
Maintainer: Ubuntu Kernel Team <kernel-team@lists.ubuntu.com>
Bugs: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+filebug
Installed-Size: 18.4 kB
Provides: virtualbox-guest-modules (= 6.1.10-dfsg-1~ubuntu1.20.04.1), wireguard-modules (= 1.0.20201112-1~20.04.1), zfs-modules (= 0.8.3-1ubuntu12.5)
Depends: linux-image-5.4.0-59-generic, linux-modules-extra-5.4.0-59-generic, linux-firmware, intel-microcode, amd64-microcode
Recommends: thermald
Download-Size: 2,584 B
APT-Sources: http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 Packages
Description: Generic Linux kernel image
 This package will always depend on the latest generic kernel image
 available.

Package: linux-image-generic
Version: 5.4.0.26.32
Priority: optional
Section: kernel
Source: linux-meta
Origin: Ubuntu
Maintainer: Ubuntu Kernel Team <kernel-team@lists.ubuntu.com>
Bugs: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+filebug
Installed-Size: 17.4 kB
Provides: virtualbox-guest-modules (= 6.1.6-dfsg-1), wireguard-modules (= 1.0.20200413-1), zfs-modules (= 0.8.3-1ubuntu12)
Depends: linux-image-5.4.0-26-generic, linux-modules-extra-5.4.0-26-generic, linux-firmware, intel-microcode, amd64-microcode
Recommends: thermald
Download-Size: 2,796 B
APT-Sources: http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 Packages
Description: Generic Linux kernel image
 This package will always depend on the latest generic kernel image
 available.
```

Comment: It should be there. Please add output of `dpkg -l | grep linux` to your question. Probably the upgrade was interrupted.

Comment: Reboot your PC and choose 5.4 kernel as a temporary fix.

Comment: from where did you get this kernel?  `apt show linux-image-generic -a` please.

Comment: @Pilot6 I've updated the question with the requested outputs

Comment: It related to upgrading kernel to the 5.8. It looks good at first site. You acn always fix it by returning to the 5.4 kernels.

Comment: So I installed inux-modules-extra-5.8.0-34-generic which appeared to be missing. Wireless now works.

However apt show linux-image-generic -a still only shows the 5.4 kernel output? What's missing

Answer (score 0):

Installing the missing linux-modules-extra-5.8.0-34-generic package provided the ath9k module.

This situation arose from a failed kernel update due to the keyutils package missing on a machine with encrypted disks.